# Define a compact set $\mathcal{U}$ such that $u_k \in \mathcal{U}$ for all $k \geq 0$

Tags: general-topology

I have vectors $u_k,u_{k-1}...u_0 \in \mathbb{R}^{\text{n}} $, that behaves following this inequality

$\Delta u_{k} \leq L_R (\Delta u_{k-1}+c)$
meaning,
$\Delta u_{k} \leq c_k$

where $\Delta u_{k}= \lVert u_{k}-u_{k-1} \rVert$, $0<L_R<1$ and $c_k, c$ are positive constants. This inequality shows that $\Delta u_{k}$ has a small ultimate bound.

Suppose $u_0$ is in a compact set $\mathcal{U}$, now I want to define $\mathcal{U}$ such that $u_k \in \mathcal{U}$ for all $k \geq 0$

Comment: Only $\Delta u_{k}$ is bounded, we are not sure whether $u_k$ itself is bounded, so $\mathcal{U}$ might not be compact at all.

Comment: You finitely many vectors, one of them has the greatest magnitude. Just take $\mathcal U$ to be the closed $n$ ball of radius equal to the greatest magnitude? This obvious though so I suspect there’s something in your question you’re not explaining well enough

Comment: @Ricky Thank you. how about this one I edited? Suppose $\mathcal{U}$ has two closed balls centered at the origin $B_1(0| r_1), B_2(0|r_2) $ with $r_2>r_1$ and $u_0$ is in $B_1$, then u_k for all $k>0$ seems contained inside $B_2$ when $r_2> k*max(c_1, c_2,...c_k)+r_1$

Comment: @Chris Thank you. So you mean $\mathcal{U}=B(0| \max( \|u_k\|,\|u_{k-1}\|,.. \|u_0\|))$ would be the one satisfying this question

Comment: @Chris Yes you're right. But I would rather you exploit the aforementioned inequality.

Comment: @SpaceTAKA why?

Comment: @Chris Cuz your suggestion would end up being circular reasoning in my context. (I want to prove $u$ never exit $\mathcal{U}$ )

Comment: @SpaceTAKA you should rewrite your question because it is unclear what you want. If you want to $\textbf{define}$ $\mathcal U$ then any compact set containing all such vectors works. Is this part of some larger problem of which the context you’ve neglected to provide?